# Multiple 100% height blocks in HTML

Tags: html, css, web

I understand that in order to use a percentage based height, the parent element must be set to a fixed height? eg 500px.

I am building a grid in which there is a hierarchy of divs. The parent is a fixed height of 500px, and the children are percentage heights, each 33.333%. These children then have a set of children, each which I want to give a percentage height of 100% of it's parent.

Any one know a way around this?

Comment: Please show us what code you have so far.

Comment: I don't understand, where's the problem? Check [here](https://jsfiddle.net/9pagr9um/), I've used only percentage dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

> Any one know a way around this?

An alternative method is to use flexbox with `flex-grow` so that children grow to fill their parent

```css
* {margin:0;}
section {
  height: 100vh;
}
section,div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
div,p {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
}
p {
  background: #eee;
}
div:nth-child(even) p {
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div>
    <p>text</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>text</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>text</p>
  </div>
</section>
```